# How to fix 'Argument(s) are different! Wanted' error in Junit and Mockito

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, junit, mockito

While executing the *JUnit* test cases which involved method that contains verify.save() method, I am getting the following error ***'Argument(s) are different! Wanted'***

```java
@Test
public void checkCorrectAttemptTest() {
    Multiplication multiplication = new Multiplication(50, 60);
    User user = new User("abc");
    MultiplicationResultAttempt attempt = new MultiplicationResultAttempt(user, multiplication, 3000, false);
    MultiplicationResultAttempt verifiedAttempt = new MultiplicationResultAttempt(user, multiplication, 3000, true);
    when(userRepository.findByAlias("abc")).thenReturn(Optional.empty());
    boolean attemptResult = multiplicaitonServiceImpl.checkAttempt(attempt);
    assertThat(attemptResult).isTrue();

    verify(attemptRepository).save(verifiedAttempt);
}
```

I get the following error message.

```java
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
attemptRepository.save(
    MultiplicationResultAttempt [user=User [alias=abc], multiplication=Multiplication [factorA=50, factorB=60], resultAttempt=3000, correct=true]
);
-> at microservices.book.multiplication.service.MultiplicationServiceImplTest.checkCorrectAttemptTest(MultiplicationServiceImplTest.java:60)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
attemptRepository.save(
    MultiplicationResultAttempt [user=User [alias=abc], multiplication=Multiplication [factorA=50, factorB=60], resultAttempt=3000, correct=true]
);
-> at microservices.book.multiplication.service.MultiplicationServiceImpl.checkAttempt(MultiplicationServiceImpl.java:58)
   at microservices.book.multiplication.service.MultiplicationServiceImplTest.checkCorrectAttemptTest(MultiplicationServiceImplTest.java:60)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use:

```
verify(attemptRepository).save(Matchers.refEq(verifiedAttempt));
```

I suspect `MultiplicationResultAttempt` doesn't implement equals based on equality on the fields of the object, so when Mockito validates the attribute it is not equal to the object that you provided, although all the fields have the same value.

`Matcher.refEq(...)` uses reflection to determine if the values are the same.

**Edit**

As @farhanlq pointed out `Matchers.refEq(..)` is deprecated, `ArgumentMatchers.refEq(...)` should be used instead.

Comment: Thank, it works. But the Matchers is deprecated. Is there any other alternate for that?

Comment: Yea, they are deprecated. Sorry. You can use ArgumentMatchers.refEq(...) instead.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't implements equals method in MultiplicationResultAttempt. Thanks.

Comment: when I add event handling the above snippet didn't work. It gives the same error. Now I override the equals and hashcode method and it works fine. Is there any other way in which get rid of overriding equals and hashcode method?

Answer (score 2):

I did implements equals and hashcode in `MultiplicationResultAttempt` and it worked!!!

Comment: Please edit and format your answer so it is readable and easier to understand your solution.